# How can I switch from premium to starter here maps?

Tags: android, here-api

I had a premium SDK evaluation for Here maps, but when my evaluation was up I decided to go with the starter SDK. However, when I signed up for a starter SDK, I wasn't given a license key, so I removed it from my manifest. Now the app crashes every time I launch it. Are there any other steps that need to be taken when downgrading the Here maps SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Starter Edition, there's no license key necessary. 
License keys are only applicable for Premium Edition.

Please keep in mind that the Premium SDK and Starter SDK are two different products (different packages/binaries/downloads/code, with slightly different APIs).

So, download the StarterSDK packages, replace your old premium ones with the Starter, and do the adaptions to code and manifest as explained in the starter SDK userguide.

If you still have a crash afterwards, please paste the stacktrace.